# How to add subreports to the main report while creating a pdf in JasperReports (iReport)

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports, ireport, subreport

I have a word doc (135 kb) that is to be converted to a pdf. I am using iReport fot this. 
I created a main report (with title, page header, column header,detail, page footer,column footer,summary). Then I created three reports (with only detail bands in it).

Now I am trying to import these three reports as subreports in the main report. I am doing this because I need the page headers pecified in the main report should come in all pages of my pdf.
I am unable to preview the finished pdf. 
Am I proceeding in the right way or else what should I do?
Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain how you added the sub reports to your report?  Are you able to preview the report in iReport?  Does it give you any error?

The more info you include, the easier it would be for us to help you out.

Screen shots might be helpful too.